# Sort by date issue

Tags: c, sorting, date-sorting

Sorry for opening another topic moments before i resolved my other issue. This issue is a bigger one. I dont know if someone will understand my code because I translated it to english. The program is working like a list of orders from the internet or something like that. You can add orders, delete them, sort them by ID or Date, you can save them and load them up. Sorting by date is my issue. For example I add dates like 2013, 2011, and 2012. When i try to sort them nothing happens, they stay in the same order. If someone understands this pls tell me what is the problem? This is a school project and I need to fix it till tomorrow. Can someone pls help me with this?

```
// according = 1 (Date) 2 = (Price)
void sort(int accor)
{
    int i,j,replace=0;
    ORDER *Pom;

    for(i=0;i<Piece-1;i++){
        for(j=0;j<Piece-1;j++){
            if(according == 1){
                if(strcmp(Item[j]->Date, Item[j+1]->Date) > 0) 
                    replace = 1; 
                else 
                    replace = 0;
            }else if(according == 2){
                if(Item[j]->Price > Item[j+1]->Price ) 
                    replace = 1; 
                else 
                    replace = 0;
            }
            if(replace){
                Pom = Item[j];
                Item[j] = Item[j+1];
                Item[j+1] = Pom;
            }
```

Comment: A minor nitpick: `Item[j+]->Date` should be `Item[j+1]->Date`.

Comment: Try to use `i` instead of `j+1` and before swapping items, check that `i` is not equal to `j`. Hope that helps.

Comment: What type is `Item[]` ? Array of `ORDER *` ?

Comment: Where is `Item` declared, how is it populated? Have you tried debugging your code? Is it getting into the `replace` check at all?

Comment: @user2448027, no using `j` and `j+1` is correct for a Bubble sort. The only reason for the `i` loop is to make sure all the elements are sorted because each `j` loop might not sort more than a single element.

Comment: @MarkRansom You're right. I didn't remember the algorithm correctly. An alternative is to use `j-1` instead of `j+1`, as done here: http://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/Bubble_sort.c.

Comment: Are tou using `accor` or `according`? Is this your real code?

Comment: I fixed the date sorting issue but now sorting by ID is not working. The program collapses when i type to sort it by ID. j-1 fixed my problem with the date sorting

Comment: This code has been translated to englisch, originally it is created in slovak language. The code works fine, just dont know why the sorting by ID is messed up now. Accor is just a in short for According. I tried my best to translate it for u guys to understand

Comment: The argument is `accor`; the code uses `according`.  Is this a transcription error?    I'd rather see accurate code with names in another language than inaccurate code that arises from transcription from one (human) language to another.  If you can't read past/through opaque names, you've not got much business programming.  The descriptive text does need to be English (SO rules), but the code shouldn't matter (though a quick, rough translation of key names might help).

Comment: Sorry if i confused you with this. I only used the short term here. I shouldve wrote void sort(int according), sorry

Answer (score 0):

Change the loops to be like the following:

```
for (i = (Piece - 1); i > 0; i--)
{
  for (j = 1; j <= i; j++)
  {
  // compare and swap
  }
}
```

Source: http://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/Bubble_sort.c

Comment: I tried this solution aswell, but it did not work. j-1 fixed the date issue, but ID is the problem now, it  crashes all the time

Comment: @eduroam Did you also replace the `j+1` with `j-1` in the part where you sort by ID? The reason for crashing is probably that some array index is out of bounds, i.e. smaller than 0 and bigger than size-1.